# How to apply patches in old non compatible version

Tags: magento-enterprise, patches, magento-1.6, supee-8967

I know this is not a right way to implement but unfortunately this is the requirement and I have some limitation for this.

I am using Magento EE 1.6.0.0 and in this version I want to apply **MasterCard BIN Range Update (8967)** patch magento has already mention that this patch is only for 1.9.0.0 and higher but the problem is I can't update this version.

Is there any way to solve this problem.

What are the impacted area and how I can apply patch which is not compatible for the version.

If I want to apply patch manually then how to achieve this.

patch details can be found at [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_21x_MasterCard.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This two files are update in SUPEE -8967 patch.

> app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cc.php
>
> js/prototype/validation.js

You can manually update the file.

Please check the files [SUPEE 8967 MasterCard Patch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172697/supee-8967-mastercard-patch?answertab=active#tab-top)

It will affect the Payment method. Once apply please check Payment methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But is it right way to implement and as magento mentioned that this is not for my version will manually made changes workes?

Comment: Yes it will work. Only two files you can do Manually in local everything is fine . you can push a code to production :)